# LGA1151 Motherboard with HDMI2.0

Tags: hdmi, intel

I am looking for an LGA1151 motherboard that has HDMI 2.0

The current one I have only has HDMI 1.4 and I can't find a suitable one. The CPU I have is an Intel Pentium G4600.

I also need:

- Form factor Mini-ITX
- Support for NVMe drives
- Preferably no WiFi

Preferably the motherboard also has the ability to always supply power to one internal USB 2.0 header, but that's just an extra.

I would really appreciate some recommendations.

Comment: https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&N=100007627%20600567584%20600009028%20600136887

Comment: Only one of those has HDMI 2.0 and it's way too expensive for an HTPC. A couple times the cost of the CPU.

Comment: That's the point, there isn't going to be anything that meets your requirement then.

Comment: Are you aware that the Igp in the G4600 is HDMI 1.4? this means that even if you get a motherboard that supports it, you will not be able to use it unles you switch to a new cpu

Comment: In fact, the HDMI port on the board is wired right into the CPU socket. So it is the CPU, not the board, that determines what signal is sent over that port. You'll need a 7th gen Intel CPU to get HDMI 2.0 support, on any 1151 board.

Answer (score 0):

The only board I see on the market is the ASRock Fatal1ty Z270 Gaming-ITX. This is because HDMI 2.0 was, for whatever reason, sparsely offered by LGA1151 boards. The alternative is Display Port. HDMI 2.0 is feature-matched by DP 1.2 and affordable adapters exist (make sure to get the right one though).

- Gigabyte GA-B250N Phoenix-WIFI
- ASUS ROG Strix H270I Gaming
- ASUS Z170I Pro Gaming
- MSI Z270I Gaming Pro Carbon AC
- Supermicro X11SSV-Q

Some of these boards come with a removable WIFI module.

You will have more luck finding cheap boards by going micro ATX (with DP, not with HDMI 2.0).